# Issues while setting up lightweight modular staging

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm trying to get started with the examples [here](http://scala-lms.github.io/tutorials/shonan.html). I'm trying to set up my dev environment using Scala IDE (Eclipse).

So far,

1. I have downloaded [lms](https://github.com/TiarkRompf/virtualization-lms-core), built it using sbt and added the generated jar library to my eclipse project.
2. I'm trying to write this bit of the code sample provided.

   ```
   val snippet = new DslDriver[Array[Int],Array[Int]] {
   def snippet(v: Rep[Array[Int]]) = {// Continues
   ```

However, DslDriver isn't found inside the scala.virtualization.lms package. The library is being found so it's not a problem with the build path.

1. I have also installed the scala-virtualized plugin to my Scala IDE.
2. Perhaps this is an eclipse issue where it can't find the necessary classes? Should I switch to coding using an editor and building using sbt?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with lms but have you tried using [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to set up your project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found a solution to your question, but the `DslDriver` class is defined in the [dslapi.scala](https://github.com/scala-lms/tutorials/blob/master/src/test/scala/lms/tutorial/dslapi.scala) file.

Checkout the whole tutorial folder.